# Removing extension from multiple selected files and only using 50 characters of it

Tags: c#, string, openfiledialog

I have two separate questions:

a) How to remove `.mp3` / `.mpeg` extensions from multiple selected files
b) When the multiple files are added to the `listbox`. How can I set a max character length (50 chars)

```
String[] files, paths;
private void addbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
        paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
        for (int x = 0; x < files.Length; x++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(files[x]);
            // How can I remove the file extentions here? I know I can't use substring right?
            // Only use 50 chars after chopping off the extentions
        }
    }
}
```

I searched google but there are no answers relating to multiple files. Thanks guys!

Comment: `I searched google but there are no answers relating to multiple files.` Because it is very unique problem, no one has faced before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and `String.Remove`:

```
string fileWithOutExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[x]);
if (fileWithOutExtension.Length > 50)
    fileWithOutExtension = fileWithOutExtension.Remove(50);
listBox1.Items.Add(fileWithOutExtension);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove .mp3 / .mpeg extensions from multiple selected files

You can use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method to get the file name without extension:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("path");
```

> b) When the multiple files are added to the listbox. How can I set a max character length (50 chars)

Use `Substring`

```
fileName = fileName.Substring(0, 50);
```